# How to manually deploy a driver service?

Tags: windows, wdm

How do i manually deploy or register a Windows filter driver?

**Warning**: There's a lot of "proof of research effort" ahead. You don't have to read any more if you don't want to. I just point out, in detail, that i've tried what you're supposed to, i've tried what MSDN says, and i've tried everything anyone anywhere on the Internet has ever suggested.

tl;dr: What's the **intended** way?

## Background

I'm testing deploying a 64-bit driver developed in Visual Studio 2013 to a 64-bit Windows machine. I want to register the driver service with Windows, and start it.

## What have you tried

- **Visual Studio 2013 Driver Deployment feature**

  Ideally you would use the [Visual Studio's capability to automatically deploy to a remote machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj863657(v=vs.85).aspx). Unfortunately it just doesn't work (*"An extended error has occurred"*)
- **Using the Add New Hardware Wizard**

  Ideally you would use the Windows **Add New Hardware Wizard** (see the MSDN page [Using the Add Hardware Wizard to Install a Driver Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553639(v=vs.85).aspx). Fortunately, starting with Windows 7, Microsoft removed the Add New Hardware Wizard from the Control Panel; requiring you to manually run `Hdwwiz.exe` from an elevated command prompt. Unfortunately you cannot use the **Add New Hardware Wizard** to add install a driver package, because the **Add New Hardware Wizard** only works with *hardware* (i.e. it doesn't work for filter drivers):

  [image]

  The wizard knows this, so doesn't offer to let you install any driver services.
- **SC Command line utility**

  Ideally you would register the driver service manually with the Service Control Manager with **`sc.exe`** tool from an elevated command prompt:

  ```
  >sc create MyDriver binPath="C:\Drop\Driver\MyDriver.sys" type=kernel
  >[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
  ```

  Unfortunately, even with a valid digital signature on the driver file:

  [image]

  Windows will refuse to install the driver:

  [image]
- **OSR's Driver Loader Utility**

  Ideally one would use [OSR's Driver Loader utility](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157). But even with a validly digitally signed driver file, the driver will not install:

  [image]
- **.INF setup file**

  Ideally you would [deploy the Driver Package and install it by installing from the `.inf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544840(v=vs.85).aspx). Then i could just right-click the INF, select **Install**. But it just doesn't work - it doesn't register any new driver service.
- **.INF setup with with DefaultInstall section**

  Ideally you would just use a `.INF` file a **DefaultInstall** section. Windows would just execute the [DefaultInstall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547356(v=vs.85).aspx) section. Unfortunately, MSDN warns that you're not allowed to use that for for drivers:

  > **Note**  The INF file of a [driver package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544840(v=vs.85).aspx) must not contain an INF **DefaultInstall** section

  The reason you can't do it is because **DefaultInstall** has no **AddService** directive. Even if we ignore the warning and try anyway it just doesn't work - it doesn't register any new driver service.
- **.INF setup with DefaultInstall.Services section**

  While MSDN warns you against using DefaultInstall to register driver services, we can ignore them and use the **`[DefaultInstall.Services]`** section. Fortunately, it actually tries to install the driver service:

  [image]

  but Windows then claims the driver is unsigned:

  [image]

  no driver service is actually registered.
- **SetupAPI InstallHinfSection function**

  Ideally i could use the SetupAPI to run the command line equivalent of the above:

  ```
  >RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 C:\Drop\Driver\ipfw.inf
  ```

  Except the driver doesn't install. The function returns successfully; but Windows thinks the driver is unsigned:

  [image]
- **Use BCDEDIT to enable TESTSIGNING**

  Ideally i would follow the instructions from [The TESTSIGNING Boot Configuration Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484(v=vs.85).aspx), which says to run from an elevated command prompt:

  ```
  >Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
  ```

  Except that fails with the error:

  ```
  >Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
  An error has occurred setting the element data.
  The value is protected by Secure Boot policy and cannot be modified or deleted.
  ```
- **Use BCDEDIT to turn DEBUG on**

  Ideally i would follow the instructions on [Installing an Unsigned Driver during Development and Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which says to run from an elevated command prompt:

  ```
  >bcdedit -debug on
  ```

  Except that fails with an error:

  ```
  >bcdedit -debug on
  An error occurred while attempting to modify the debugger settings.
  The value is protected by Secure Boot policy and cannot be modified or deleted.
  ```
- **Use advanced recovery options to disable driver signing enforcement**

  Ideally i would use the advanced recovery options to disable driver signature enforcement:

  [image]

  Except after Windows starts driver signing is still enabled:

  [image]
- **Disable SecureBoot in the BIOS**

  Ideally in this virtual Hyper-V computer i would disable SecureBoot in its virtual BIOS:

  [image]

  and then try disabling the driver signing policy.

And oh my god three days on this. I'd like someone from Microsoft to explain:

- not only the correct way to test drivers during development
- but to explain, in detail, why each of the above attempts failed

## What's the proper way

Rather than me trying random things, over, and over (and over, and over. And over), what is the ***right*** way to install a filter driver service?

## Bonus Question

Why does Microsoft refuse to make life easier for developers?

## Bonus Chatter

The driver file is signed with a valid, trusted, certificate.

[image]

The certificate that signs the .sys driver file is also located in the *Local Machine* **Trusted Root Certificates** store:

[image]

That is why the driver file's signature is valid and trusted.

A throwaway comment on [a random page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547618(v=vs.85).aspx) says that test certificates must be added to two locations in the local machine store:

> The [test certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553457(v=vs.85).aspx)s that are used to embed signatures in driver files and to sign a [driver package's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544840(v=vs.85).aspx) [catalog file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537872(v=vs.85).aspx) must be added to
>
> - the [**Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553506(v=vs.85).aspx)
> - and the [**Trusted Publishers certificate store**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553504(v=vs.85).aspx).

Which explains why i added the certificate to another store:

[image]

Windows 10 Technical Preview, 64-bit

## Bonus Reading

- [Using the Add Hardware Wizard to Install a Driver Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553639(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Using an INF File to Install a File System Filter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557251(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Using an INF File to Uninstall a File System Filter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557255(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Writing a Device Installation Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554015(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [INF DefaultInstall Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547356(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Installing Test Certificates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Installing a Test Certificate on a Test Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547618(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Using CertMgr to Install Test Certificates on a Test Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553563(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So, did disabling Secure Boot have any effect?  For example, does bcdedit still complain about Secure Boot policy after Secure Boot was disabled?  It might also be worth trying installing a new VM configured to use BIOS rather than UEFI, and/or one where Secure Boot was turned off before installation.  (Although it could, I suppose, simply be a bug or limitation in the Windows 10 preview.  I assume it all works as documented in Windows 8.1?)

Comment: Good man, I see you're using the Technical Preview also.
On Windows 7, what I do is (after dealing with signature enforcement; not as much of an issue on 7) add both certificates to the default store.
Then I go to the Device Manager, right click on my computer (top of the tree), then select "Add Legacy Hardware."
I then go through the "Have Disk" option to install my custom driver.
However, on the Technical Preview, I've noticed this fails without offering reason. I hope you find an answer, and perhaps that this comment helps someone out there.

Comment: 1) Disable Secure Boot. 2) Enable TESTSIGNING. 3) Reboot,

Answer (score 0):

And if you still cannot and no certificate problems, I have done it like so:

`devcon install irpsender\irpsender.inf Root\irpsender`

Where Root\irpsender comes from the .inf file:

```
[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
%irpsender.DeviceDesc%=irpsender_Device, Root\irpsender ; TODO: edit hw-id
```

My approach, although successful in some older Win10 did not work on Win8.1 - I have created a service like above and started it; `DriverEntry` does get called and nothing else. Also got the

```
c:\DriverTest\Drivers>sc stop irpsender
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1052:

The requested control is not valid for this service.
```

Probably because of no hardware ID specified as well.

HTH